# PHP How to sort results ASC

Tags: php

Can someone help me add a sort function here... I need the "if" results to be sorted ASC by floorplan_price.

```
if ($this->floorplan=ipropertyHTML::getcatfloorplan($this->catinfo->id))
{
echo '<h2 class="ip-floorplan-header" style="margin-top:-50px;color:#B20839; font-weight: bold;">Available Floorplans To Build</h2>';

  $this->k = 0;
  $this->floorplan=ipropertyHTML::getcatfloorplan($this->catinfo->id);

  foreach($this->floorplan as $fp)
  {
    $this->floorplan_price=$fp->floorplan_price;
    $this->floorplaninfo=ipropertyHTML::getfloorplaninfo($fp->floorplan_id);
    $this->p= $this->floorplaninfo;
    echo $this->loadTemplate('floorplan');
    $this->k = 1 - $this->k;
  }}
else { // no results tmpl

    echo '<h2 class="ip-floorplan-header" style="margin-top:-50px;color:#B20839; font-weight: bold;">Available Floorplans To Build</h2>';
    echo '<div class="nofloorplans">No floor plans are available to build at the time. Check back soon!</div>';

}
```

Comment: Can you change the SQL query or do you have to work with the object?

Comment: Your second `ipropertyHTML::getcatfloorplan($this->catinfo->id);` is redundant, `$this->floorplan` is already set with the return of that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function allows you to provide the logic for sorting.

Define the sorting method:

```
function sortByPrice($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->floorplan_price == $b->floorplan_price) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->floorplan_price < $b->floorplan_price) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Then above your foreach loop

```
usort($this->floorplan, "sortByPrice");
```

I will note, as @Sébastien did, that this should be a job for MySQl not php if at all possible, simply for performance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on changing the MySQL query? I'm a total novice when it comes to PHP and MySQL. I can find my way around and edit some stuff, but when it comes to writing this stuff from scratch... I'm lost. How will it improve performance? I'm not questioning it at all... just would like to know how it can work best. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Post your current query. The one `getcatfloorplan` uses.